# Image of a differentiable map

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable map, with a Jacobian that is almost everywhere non zero, $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $q=\phi(p)$. If the rank of the Jacobian matrix of $\phi$ at $p$ is $n$, then for every every direction $v$ we have that $q+\varepsilon v\in \text{ Image}(\phi)$ for all small enough $\varepsilon$. How can I describe those directions $v$ such that $q+\varepsilon v\in \text{ Image}(\phi)$ for all small enough $\varepsilon$ if the rank is not $n$? Since the Jacobian is almost everywhere non zero, one knows that for almost all directions $w$ we have that $p+\varepsilon w$ will a point such that the Jacobian is fully ranked. Thus at $q_0=\phi(p+\varepsilon_0 w)$ for small enough positive $\varepsilon_0$ every direction $v_0$ will give us that $v_o+\varepsilon q_0\in \text{ Image}(\phi)$ for small enough $\varepsilon$. Does this somehow help?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the Jacobian looks like anywhere except at $p$. Any neighborhood for a point other than $p$ need not extend to $p$. The best you can say is that $\text{Image}(\phi)$ contains a hyper-surface containing $q$ whose dimension is the rank of the Jacobian of $\phi$ at $p$.

Comment: Hmm are there any additional properties of the map that I could use?

Comment: You didn't list any addtional properties. So, no.

Comment: @PaulSinclair In this case (when the rank of the Jacobian is less than n), is it certain that there are directions that are not included in the image?
If I understand correctly, then what we need to do is to calculate the Hessian matrices ($n$ matrices), take the linear combination of these matrices that corresponds to the linear dependent of the Jacobian columns at point $p$, and check if its semidefinite. If not, then all directions are included in $\text{Image}(\phi)$. Is this right?

Comment: @user3350919 - $\phi'(p)$ is a linear map. If you traverse the curve $t\mapsto p + tv$ in $\Bbb R^n$, the image under $\phi$ starts off at $t = 0$ traveling in the direction $\phi'(p)v$. If a vector $u$ in $\Bbb R^m$ is not in the image of $\phi'(p)$, then no curve through $p$ will have an image moving in the direction of $u$ at $q$. Now $\phi$ may curve around to pick up points in the $u$ direction, but the paths to them will leave $q$ in a different direction, not $u$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for your answer. I'm looking at a similar problem (with a slight difference that the map $S\rightarrow T$ with $S\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $m<n$. $T_i(S)$ are multinomials that are linear in each $s_j$ separately, e.g, $T_1=s_1s_2s_3 + s_2s_3s_5+s_1s_4s_5$.)
I want to claim that for any $S$, if I take a small ball around it, the image contains a small ball around $T(S)$. The difficulty is that there are points $S$ where the jacobian is not full rank. I am wondering if I can still claim that all directions are possible, maybe due to Sard's theorem?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I forgat to say that in most points the jacobian is full rank, but there is a curve in $S$ that have rank deficient jacobian

Comment: I'm sorry, but if the jacobian is not full rank at some $S\in \Bbb R^n$, there are directions at $T(S) \in \Bbb R^m$ that are not possible to travel in by moving $S$. That is exactly what it means for the Jacobian to not be full rank. Sard's theorem doesn't help because it does not matter what the Jacobian is at some point $\ne S$. There is a neighborhood around that other point in which you can move in all directions. But that neighborhood will not extend to include $S$. It doesn't matter even if $S$ is completely surrounded by such points. None of the neighborhoods will extend to $S$.